# Transferencia de un directorio de un servidor a otro

Tags: linux, servidor, cron

Amigos estoy tratando de transferir un directorio de un servidor A a un servidor B.

Para ello en el servidor A hice lo siguiente:

1ro en el servidor A creé el archivo respaldo.sh que hace lo siguiente:

```
cd  /u01/seguridad # (entrar primero a la ubicación del archivo)
scp -r DOCS_SEGURIDAD backup@192.168.101.17:/u07/semanal # (quiero que se envíe al usuario backup, servidor cuya ip es 192.168.101.17 en la ubicación /u07/semanal)
```

2do programé el crontab

```
* * * * * /root/respaldo.sh  # (ya que el archivo respaldo.sh se encuentra en root, y quiero que se replique cada minuto)
```

Ya hice la prueba a transferir el archivo si hacer uso del cron y se pudo con éxito, pero obviamente me pidió la contraseña. ¿Cómo haría ahora que estoy usando un cron para lo de la contraseña?

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Usa ssh keys entre ambos si puedes, es lo más practico creo. Es decir, en el servidor A creas una SSH key para el usuario root, y luego, la parte publica de la key creada, la agregas al archivo /home/backup/.ssh/authorized_keys en el Servidor B, y ya no te pedira contraseña seguramente.

Comment: .... y entonces verifica que scp use la llave privada para que funcione sin la contraseña. Por cierto, no tiene que ser para el usuario root. Cualquier usuario puede hacer ese trabajo de crear las llaves (lo más sencillo es hacerlo con el usuario para el que estés configurando el cronjob, obviamente).

Comment: Como parece que todos saben la respuesta pero no quieren escribirla, voy a hacer una respuesta de la comunidad para que me ayuden a editarla

Comment: @Cuauhtli No hay piedad por lo que veo... habia tenido que salir un momento :-)

Comment: @eftshift0 En este caso, al estar el script en /root/respaldo.sh, di por sentado que era el root el que necesitaba la key sin querer liarle demasiado con más parametros en la instrucción, pero si, se puede hacer sin que sea la key del root tal como dices.

Comment: @masterguru :') Ya hice la respuesta como respuesta de la comunidad (porque parece que todos los que comentaron tenían idea de qué hacer). La pueden editar como quieran para mejorar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El programa `scp` utiliza el protocolo `ssh`, por lo que para subir archivos de la computadora A a la B, necesitarás de depositar la llave pública de A en el archivo `/home/usuarioB/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

De esa manera, podrás conectarte de A a B ya sea como servidor remoto o con SCP para trasferencia de archivos.

Si creaste tus llaves sin passphrase, `scp`no te va a pedir contraseña.

Puedes primero hacer lo siguiente.

En la computadora A, con el usuario que quieras, digamos *user1*, creamos nuestro par de llaves con:

```
$ ssh-keygen
```

Das enter a todo para aceptar, y tu par de llaves se debió haber creado en la carpeta: `/home/user1/.ssh/id_rsa`

La llave pública la copiaremos a la computadora B. Y para esto podemos copiar lo que nos arroja el comando:

```
$ cat /home/user1/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
ssh-rsa ...
```

Y lo pegamos en el archivo: `/home/<usuario remoto de B>/.ssh/authorized_keys`, en el servidor B.

De esta manera seremos capaces de establecer conexión con ssh de A a B.

Ahora, con ese mismo usuario, podrás crear tu crontab con `$ crontab -e`:

```
* * * * * scp -r /u01/seguridad/DOCS_SEGURIDAD backup@192.168.101.17:/u07/semanal
```